# Do Random Variables have to be bijective?

Tags: probability, random-variables

This question has been [asked before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202540/is-a-random-variable-bijective) 
Let me clarify what I don't get about each of the responses.

The first response (Michael Hardy): To me, it seems like this answer is comparing apples to oranges(no offense to the answerer: I am sure I am wrong). Michael defines a new random variable `(X1,X2,X3)`, which looks bijective to me. However, he goes on to say that `X1` is not bijective. This makes little sense to me.

The second response (Qiaochu Yuan):

> $X^{−1}$ is not the inverse. It is the inverse image.

I believe the answer's saying that the Real numbers is infinite but the event space could be defined to have finite size, thus bijectivity doesn't apply because the size of codomain is larger than the size of the domain. While this is true, I can always change the set getting mapped to from real numbers to the numbers I map to. Ok, I am cheating a bit. Can anyone elaborate on this?

The third response (M Turgeon):

> No, it doesn't have to be bijective - take a constant function.

Ok, this one logically makes sense. Unfortunately, overly constructed contradictions sometimes fail to change my instinct, and this is one of those cases. An example of a use case for a constant random variable would be helpful.

Please note that I am not familiar with Groups/Algebra, Topology or Analysis/Measure Theory.

What I want: I would like answers that expound on the answers to the question I have linked. Addressing the concerns I have mentioned in the question would be nice, but isn't necessary in interest of the response being useful to the community.

Comment: What is your question? The function $X_1$ mentioned above is a simple example of a measurable function that it not bijective. Qiaochu's answer is clarifying what appears to be some confusion on your part, which is that $X^{-1}$ refers to the inverse image, and not an inverse function. A random variable is just a measurable function. You asked if all random variables are bijective and a constant function is a reasonable example. You should add comments to ask for clarification on the other question rather than asking a question about a question.

Comment: Its okay to not know the topics you list in your last line, but do you at the very least understand elementary set theory and the definition of what it means to be bijective?  MichaelHardy's answer gives an example of a sample space and a random variable on that sample space such that there are many elementary events corresponding to the same outcome, something which should not happen for a bijective function.

Comment: In very simple terms, the random variable is a map for sample space to probability.  Meaning different elements in the probability space might have the same probability. Take the experiment of tossing two coins. P(0 head)=P(2 heads)=0.25. But if you take the cumulative distribution function of random variable that is in fact bijective on $S\to [0,1]$. where $S$ is the sample space.

Comment: Also, side note: writing "no offense to the answerer" is more or less incompatible with following it by "The guy [...]."

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for letting me know. I was debating that when writing the question. In retrospect, I should have called him by his name.

Comment: @copper.hat I had some fundamental mistakes in my line of thinking that made your reasoning hard to follow. Your comment makes sense in context of the Mike's answer below now. I didn't know inverse images were different from inverse functions. Thanks! I don't think I could write comments back then since I had no rep.

Comment: @copper.hat added a short paragraph at the end about what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When you have a random vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, each coordinate $X_i$ is a random variable. Michael Hardy is saying that the random variable $X_1$ is not injective.
2. You are right; you can always change the codomain to make the random variable surjective. 
   Consider the opposite problem; suppose that the probability space $\Omega$ is infinite, while the range of the random variable is finite. Something like, flip a coin over and over until the result is heads, and let $X=1$ if the number of flips is odd and $X=0$ otherwise. The sample space is $\{H,TH,TTH,TTTH,\dots\}$, but the range is $\{0,1\}$. This random variable is essentially not bijective.
3. Imagine an urn with $100$ white balls and $101$ black balls. Over and over, remove two random balls from the urn. If they are the same color, throw in a white ball. If they are different colors, throw in a black ball. Continue (for 200 draws total) until there is only one ball left.
   You would agree that the color of the last ball is a random variable, yes? It is the result of a series of random decisions. However, you can prove that no matter what sequence of random draws you make, the last ball will always be black! This is a constant random variable which arises "in the real world."

Comment: I understand the second point; I need to think more about the third point, but I think I can understand it after some more thinking. I would like to ask some clarification for the first point: don't we care about the random vector being injective (instead of the random variables that comprise the random vector)?

Comment: @YoloVoe Michael Hardy's goal was to find a counterexample, and $X_1$ proved to be a counter example. In light of this, it does matter whether the vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is injective. Just forget about the other variables $X_2,X_3$, and consider $X_1$ on the same probability space, and there is your non-injective counterexample.

Comment: @YoloVoe Also, there are less silly examples of important constant random variables. For example, the Strong Law of Large numbers implies that when $X_1,X_2,\dots,$ is a sequence of independent coin flips, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\text{# heads in }X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)/n$ is (almost surely) constant and equal to $\frac12$. The limit depends on a sequence of random variables, so is itself random, but it is almost surely constant; most sequences result in 1/2. The point is that constant random variables are not an arbitrary counterexample, they show up in important and unexpected places.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation and comments were really helpful and got to the crux of the matter and clarified my confusion! :)

Comment: @YoloVoe Happy to talk about probability theory with an interested audience!